# Update source data through chart in Python

Tags: python, data-visualization, streamlit

Is there any way in Python to modify the source data by moving data points in the chart?

This is intended to work in [streamlit](https://streamlit.io/docs/api.html): I'd like to make it convenient for users to edit multiple parameters of the same kind visually changing the curve which represents series of parameters and their corresponding value. As far as I know, streamlit currently supports Matplotlib, Plotly, Altair, Bokeh, Vega Lite, Deck.GL, dagre-d3 charts, but not sure whether any of those libraries provide this functionality.

Comment: This question will probably be closed since asking for software recommendations is explicitly called out as inappropriate for Stack Overflow. If you would like to discuss Bokeh's edit tools, pease come by the project Discourse http://discourse.bokeh.org/c/community-support

Comment: Hi @mentalmushroom -- I invite you to check out the extremely active [Streamlit discussion forum](https://discuss.streamlit.io/) where you can explore the space of what users are doing with Streamlit. 

Thanks for experimenting with Streamlit!